# GUI tool to backup PPAs and list of packages

Tags: package-management, backup, ppa, gui

I am looking for a GUI tool to backup and restore the list of PPAs and packages installed on the system.

I was using [Aptik](https://github.com/teejee2008/aptik) but now the free version is not maintained anymore and I need an alternative.

That tool was useful to me because I could see the list of PPAs and a column with the list of packages installed by the specific PPA. Besides, in the list of packages I could see a description of each package in order to better choose and at first access to that view a default pre-selection was made (based on I don't which what logic).

That's why I am looking for something with GUI and not simply CLI solutions.

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Thanks